# Generic Module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have all common function in a module Helper. Those function will work only if it include a constants file which is dynamic based on every project. Now, what is the best approach to reuse the module?

```
module Helper
  #dunno how to include the constants file and reuse it
  def morning_food(who)
   puts FOOD_HABIT[:morning]
  end
end
```

../Constant files

```
module Animal
 module Constants
 FOOD_HABIT = {
  morning: "a",
  ...
 }
 end
end

module Person
 module Constants
 FOOD_HABIT = {
  morning: "dosa",
  ...
 }
 end
end
```

A better example: I want to build a customized complex query generator gem which can be reused across multiple project! So, apart from user selected filters, we can have default filter values for each metrics which is different for each project! Those default constants would be in a constants file. Now I want to reuse the helper method in each project.

```
module QueryBuilder
 module Helper
  #include the constants file dynamically! 
  def default_value(metrics)
    # fetch and return the values
  end
 end
end

.. /constants files
module ProjectX
 module Query
  module Constants
   DEFAULT_VALUES = {
  }
  end
 end
end



module ProjectY
 module Query
  module Constants
   DEFAULT_VALUES = {
  }
   end
 end
end
```

I guess this would make better sense!

Comment: I would strongly advise against calling a module `Helper` in a Rails app since helpers already have a specific meaning in the Rails context. Helpers in Rails are functionality which is automatically loaded into your views and or controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the module in the module, where it is needed. If you need it in the class, then use `include`

```
module Animal
 module Constants
   extend Helper
```

Comment: This makes `morning_food` a module method of `Constants`, which is kinda non-sense here.

Comment: I would say that the OP's whole example is kind of nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Helper
  #dunno how to include the constants file and reuse it
  def morning_food
   puts self.class.const_get('Constants::FOOD_HABIT')[:morning]
  end
end

class Animal
 module Constants
   FOOD_HABIT = {
     morning: "a",
   }
 end
 include Helper
end

class Person
 module Constants
   FOOD_HABIT = {
     morning: "dosa",
   }
 end
 include Helper
end

Person.new.morning_food
#⇒ "dosa"
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you should be creating a domain object (an object that reflects a real-world noun).

Animal and Person share functionality, and I am guessing there will be more shared functionality.

A good approach might be to therefore to use inheritance, and simply pass the Person/Animal object an options hash for the eating habits.

```
class Organism

  attr_accessor :morning, :evening #etc..

  def initialize(options={})
    options.each do |attribute, value|
      self.send "#{attribute}=", value
    end
  end

end

class Person < Organism

  # Person methods

end

class Animal < Organism

  # Animal methods

end
```